# c++ process does not stop

Tags: c++, multithreading

There is something wrong in the code but I do not understand why. 
I think one of the reason could be the threads that I used in the code.

The code looks like this.

in main.cpp

```
   vector<thread> t;
vector<future<myClass>> futures;
vector<myClass> chV;

for(int i = 0; i < NumberOfThreads; i++) // NumberOfThreads are 2 here
{
    promise<myClass> promises;
    futures.push_back(promises.get_future());
    t.push_back(thread(MyFunction ,i, PointsNumberInThreads , pointList, std::move(promises)));
}

for_each(t.begin(), t.end(), std::mem_fn(&std::thread::join));

for(int i = 0; i < futures.size(); i++ )
{
//        futures.at(i).get().fOut(i); // <-- if I comment out then it gives error. but why?
    chV.push_back(futures.at(i).get());
}
myClass c1 = chV.at(0);
myClass c2 = chV.at(1);
cout << "merge start" << endl; // <-- it prints out
c1.Merge(c2);
cout << "merge end" << endl; // <-- does not print out this message. so I have to kill the process
```

the Merge function in the myClass.cpp I have these sentences at the bottom of the function.

```
int aSt,aMid,aEnd;
int bSt,bMid,bEnd;

aSt = 0, aEnd = upperV.size(), aMid = (aEnd + aSt)/2;
bSt = 0, bEnd = b.upperV.size(), bMid = (bEnd + bSt)/2;

Point aPoint, bPoint, aPrev, aNext, bPrev, bNext;
aPoint = upperV.at(aMid);
aPrev = upperV.at(aMid-1);
aNext = upperV.at(aMid+1);
bPoint = b.upperV.at(bMid);
bPrev = b.upperV.at(bMid-1);
bNext = b.upperV.at(bMid+1);

bool done = true;

while(done)
{
    done = false;
    if(orientation(aPoint,bPoint,bPrev) > 0)
    {
        bEnd = bMid;
        bMid = (bEnd + bSt)/2;
        bPoint = b.upperV.at(bMid);
        done = true;
    }
    if(orientation(aPoint,bPoint,bNext) > 0)
    {
        bSt = bMid;
        bMid = (bEnd + bSt)/2;
        bPoint = b.upperV.at(bMid);
        done = true;
    }

    if(orientation(bPoint,aPoint,aPrev) < 0)
    {
        aEnd = aMid;
        aMid = (aEnd + aSt)/2;
        aPoint = upperV.at(aMid);
        done = true;
    }
    if(orientation(bPoint,aPoint,aNext) < 0)
    {
        aSt = aMid;
        aMid = (aEnd + aSt)/2;
        aPoint = upperV.at(aMid);
        done = true;
    }
}

cout << "aPoint = (" << aPoint.x << " , " << aPoint.y << ")" << endl;
cout << "bPoint = (" << bPoint.x << " , " << bPoint.y << ")" << endl;
```

and they are printed but as I mentioned the process seems to keep running in somewhere.

Comment: Please edit your post, and instead of isolated code fragments you need to post a [mcve].

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I just edited. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, but your sample code still fails at least the "minimum", and "complete" requirements of a [mcve].

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I am sorry but I think it is the minimal and complete example that I can show.

Comment: `done = true`, `while(done)`, `done = false`... what kind of weird construct is this? Don't you mean `while(!done)`? Or at least that you want a do-while? Also, `0` is an endless loop.

Comment: @William Kappler , how about if I modify like while(done==true). But it goes out the while loop and prints the last two sentences.

Comment: @Q123 What I'm getting at is... it's really weird how you've phrased what you are doing, and that compounds the fact that the actual meat of it makes little sense to an outsider. But you generally wouldn't say `while( done )` in any kind of system and I suspect even having that suggests some king of logical error in the system. You generally loop while you haven't finished...

Comment: I think you should try a debugger. If it's in an endless loop, just halt it while running. That should explain what is wrong.

Comment: @William Kappler, Thank you for your comment . But , I do not think it is in an endless loop, because , for example if it has this sentence in the while loop, cout << "test" << endl , then the "test" would be printed until I halt the process in the endless loop. But it printed it out only four times and printed very last two cout sentences.

Comment: You should probably print out all of your variables at the top (inside) of the while loop, then you will discover that you have some state where your variables collapse and you continually set `done` to `true`. I too find it confusing that you have worded your code so that the loop is only done when done is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the section of code that I think you should be concerned with. This may
not be why your code is continuing execution as you have stated in your problem, but from the code that you did provide to us; I still think this is an issue that should be addressed.

```
bool done = true;

while(done)
{
    done = false;
    if(orientation(aPoint,bPoint,bPrev) > 0)
    {
        bEnd = bMid;
        bMid = (bEnd + bSt)/2;
        bPoint = b.upperV.at(bMid);
        done = true;
    }
    if(orientation(aPoint,bPoint,bNext) > 0)
    {
        bSt = bMid;
        bMid = (bEnd + bSt)/2;
        bPoint = b.upperV.at(bMid);
        done = true;
    }

    if(orientation(bPoint,aPoint,aPrev) < 0)
    {
        aEnd = aMid;
        aMid = (aEnd + aSt)/2;
        aPoint = upperV.at(aMid);
        done = true;
    }
    if(orientation(bPoint,aPoint,aNext) < 0)
    {
        aSt = aMid;
        aMid = (aEnd + aSt)/2;
        aPoint = upperV.at(aMid);
        done = true;
    }
}
```

You are initially setting this to be true. You are then going into your while loop and are setting it to false. All of your if statements set it back to true. So if any of these conditions are met depending on what `orientation()` returns then you are not going to break out of this while loop. It may seem to be illogical at first, but I learned over time that a good way to do while loops is in this structure.

```
 bool done = false; 

 while ( !done ) {  

     // terminating case - I usually almost always check for this first!
     if ( done ) {
        break;
     }

     // Do work here and one or more cases could trip done to be equal to true 
     // within a if... else if ... else statement or within a series of if satements 
     // or none of them can, but if they don't then it must be set at the end of the while loop.

     // Any one of these or all of them could set done = true and if they don't
     // then you should set done = true at the end of the while loop since
     // if none of these conditions are met, it will execute the assignment
     // before it begins to loop.
     if ( some condidition ) {
          // Do this
     } else if ( some other condidition ) {
          // Do this instead
     } else {
          // Then do this
     }

     // Or this: Any of these could trip done = true or none of them
     // and once again if none of them do, it should be the last thing done
     // before the ending brace to your while loop.
     if ( this ) {
         // Do Work;
     }
     if ( this ) {
         // Do Work;
     }
     // etc.

     // Set this last if none of the if statements trip done to be true;
     // otherwise if one or more does trip done, then you can omit this line.
     // Note: If none of the if statements trip this flag and you trip it here
     // in this section, this loop will occur only one time.
     done = true;           
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. However, in your example(below part) the if statement would be visited only once, isn't it?

Comment: @Q123 It depends. Some of your conditions may trip the flag and if one or more does under certain circumstances then you don't need to set it at the end. It is only when all of the if statements do not trip it. I edited the post above in the comment section above the `done = true` part to reflect this so there is less confusion. To answer your question from your comment above; if none of the conditions trip `done = true` and you set this at the end then yes it would loop only once. It is a rare occurrence to have this at the end, usually some conditional if statement will trip this flag.